# Using regex to just read out of own intervals

Tags: php, regex

hello this is my text content

```
data1='res1', data2='res2', data3 = 'anything like data5='', get complete', data4 = 'anything'
```

I want to use php regex to get all (data) and (data value) but there is problem. my problem is `data3` value `(anything like data5='', get complete)` content `data5=''` and `data 5` is value not a data key! 
And in my program, `data5` detecting as separate key While this is just the value of `data3` and must detect in the array of all value in my *regex*.
 What regex can i use to solve this problem and regex read `data1`,`data2`,`data3`,`data4` separate from (`rest1`, `res2`, (anything like `data5=''`, `get complete`), anything)?

Comment: edit complete.please read 3 end lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data structure is fixed you can use something like this:

```
$re = "~ ([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)' \h*,\h*
         ([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)' \h*,\h*
         ([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)' \h*,\h*
         ([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)'         ~x";

$subst = " $1 -> $2\n $3 -> $4\n $5 -> $6\n $7 -> $8\n";

$data = "data1='res1', data2='res2', data3 = 'anything like data5='', get complete', data4 = 'anything'\n\ndata1='res1', data2='res2', data3 = 'anything like data5=''', data4 = 'anything'\n# Odds single quote\ndata1=''res1', data2='res2', data3 = 'anything like data5=''', data4 = 'anything'\n# Even quotes inside data1\ndata1='''res1', data2='res2', data3 = 'anything like data5=''', data4 = 'anything'";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $data);

print_r($result);
```

**Input**

> data1='res1', data2='res2', data3 = 'anything like data5='', get complete', data4 = 'anything'

**Output** <kbd>[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ccNaGA)</kbd>

> data1 -> res1
>   data2 -> res2
>   data3 -> anything like data5='', get complete
>   data4 -> anything

---

**Regex Breakout** <kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO5lT7/3)</kbd>

*All 4 sections*

```
~                                 # regex start delimiter
([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)' \h*,\h* # data1
([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)' \h*,\h* # data2
([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)' \h*,\h* # data3
([^\W_]+) \h*=\h* '(.*?)'         # data4
~x                                # close delimiter with 'x' freespace flag
```

*Details of a single data section (e.g. data1)*

```
([^\W_]+) # 1 or more alphanumeric chars (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9])
          # the round brackets save them in $1 group
\h*=\h*   # zero or more horizontal whitespace chars then a literal '='
          # followed by zero or more whitespace chars again
'(.*?)'   # a single quote "'", zero o more chars of any type, closing quote "'"
          # the lazy modifiers '?' makes it stop at the first single quote 
          # that satisfy also the rest of the regex(!)
\h*,\h*   # zero or more horizontal whitespace chars then a literal comma ','
          # followed by zero or more whitespace chars again
```

Comment: @Justmyhope2016: I start with "**If** *the data structure is fixed*", if you have input in different forms please update the question. The lazy regex needs an anchor to behave correctly, in your case using ``([^\W_]+)\h*=\h*'(.*)'$`` is the simplest way to solve (but update the question if you want a complete answer that works on all the inputs).